# Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded

Tags: java, jvm, cloud-foundry, btrace

I need to execute the following command from a web application deployed on `cloudfoundry`.

```
String javaHome = System.getenv("JAVA_HOME");
String javaLocation = javaHome+"/bin/java";

String command = javaLocation+" -Xms256m -Xmx512m -Dcom.sun.btrace.probeDescPath=. -Dcom.sun.btrace.dumpClasses=false -Dcom.sun.btrace.debug=false -Dcom.sun.btrace.unsafe=false -cp "+btraceLib+":"+toolsLib+ " com.sun.btrace.client.Main "+pid+" "+probeScript;

Process p = runTime.exec(command);
```

But I get the following error:

```
Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
```

I tried with different bounds on heap-size for jvm but get the same error.

How can I resolve the error?

Comment: I started with the  <a href="http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2012/05/09/running-workers-on-cloud-foundry-with-spring/">Workers on Cloudfoundry</a> Weblog, and the twitter2rabbit app. After building and running this app I proceeded to use and build (mvn clean install) just the twitter2rabbit portion. I've included the app portion of the example in the answer below.

Comment: http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2012/05/09/running-workers-on-cloud-foundry-with-spring/

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
Process p = runTime.exec(command);
```

To:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to demonstrate with this answer. Please elaborate - we'd all benefit from your efforts. :)

Comment: The important line is:        

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the 'real' solution, but I downgraded to java 1.6 from 1.7 (where I had the same issue) and I could profile the application without this error.